# How can I get this Data Frame to display the most recurring words

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a Bayesian Classification on review paragraphs to detect whether a review will have a positive or negative sentiment based on the words used in an excel file.

Below Im trying to count the words within each row within a given column and finding the ones that have a min recurrence of 100 and a min length of 4.

The reviewWords variable is basically a call using pandas to read data from a specific column rather than all of them, i.e `df = pd.read_excel(path)`. The variable also has already removed all non-alphanumeric characters and has changed everything to lower case.

When run, the program doesn't throw an error but instead just print out the columns itself. I'm not sure why it keeps doing this, I tried to get it to print out something like this:

> "word" = "how many times word Occurs"

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
def countOccurences():
minWordLength = 4
minWordOccurence = 100
wordOccurences = {}
for word in reviewWords:
    if (len(word)>=minWordLength):
        if (word in wordOccurences):
            wordOccurences[word] = wordOccurences[word] + 1

       else:
            wordOccurences[word]=1    
         for word in wordOccurences:

         if wordOccurences[word]>=minWordOccurence:
            print("These are the occurences : "+ word + ":" + str(wordOccurences[word]))
```

Comment: recurrence in a given row or in total? are you able to show some sample data?

Comment: Hi! Please consider including some data. You may find helpful reading [how to create a minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: recurrence in total, the idea is that will search through all rows of reviews and find words that meet the minimum requirements given. I cant really post the excel sheet here if that the data you need to see

Comment: Question is rather about pandas, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `bayesian` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (please edit & remove them).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```py
df=pd.Series(reviewWords)
vc = df.loc[df.str.len()>minWordLength].value_counts()
vc[vc > minWordOccurence]
```